# ng-repeat is only showing the last value

Tags: angularjs, pug, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to Angular and method ng-repeat here is my issue:

I'm making tests to learn, here is what I want to achieve now: loop through a table of table to display some content

My issue is: second ng-repeat only shows the last value.

here is my declaration in the controller:

```
app.controller("ClientCtrl", function($scope){
$scope.ClientSections = [
    {title: 'Titre 1', element: 
        [{name: 'Toto', name: 'Contenu 1', name: 'Contenu 2', name: 'Contenu 3'}]
    },
    {title: 'Titre 2', element: 
        [{name: 'Titi', name: 'Contenu 2'}]
    },
    {title: 'Titre 3', element: 
        [{name: 'Titre 1', name: 'Contenu 3'}]
    }
];
});
```

here is my pug template

```
element(ng-repeat="ClientSection in ClientSections")
    h2 {{ClientSection.title}}
        item(ng-repeat="Client in ClientSection.element")
            p {{Client.name}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because your `element` object is an array with only one `json` in it, update your `element` to become:

```
element: 
    [{name: 'Toto'}, {name: 'Contenu 1'}, {name: 'Contenu 2'}, {name: 'Contenu 3'}]
```

And of course the same must be done to all of your objects.

Comment: @Sunkhern You're welcome, kindly mark it as the correct answer for future references :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to close the braces

```
app.controller("ClientCtrl", function($scope){
$scope.ClientSections = [
    {title: 'Titre 1', element: 
        [{name: 'Toto'}, {name: 'Contenu 1'}, {name: 'Contenu 2'}, {name: 'Contenu 3'}]
    },
    {title: 'Titre 2', element: 
        [{name: 'Titi'}, {name: 'Contenu 2'}]
    },
    {title: 'Titre 3', element: 
        [{name: 'Titre 1'}, {name: 'Contenu 3'}]
    }
];
```